# Model Selection, Tree-Based Algorithms, Multiple Comparisons, and Hypothesis Testing

Tags: feature-selection, model-selection, multiple-comparisons, cart, boosting

Only data scientist in an organization and I could really use a sounding board here.

In Phase One of a project I deployed four models and served their average as the prediction. I used Random Forest regressor, AdaBoost regressor, Gradient Boosting regressor, and XGB regressor.

I was able to capture data on the back end for each individual model as well as the served prediction. It turned out that AdaBoost was giving the best results with respect to my metric of choice: mean absolute error.

In Phase One of this project I didn't perform any feature selection at all.

Phase two of the project is underway and I am attempting to get better predictions, and it is my hypothesis that performing feature selection will improve model performance.

I've got few feature selection methods I will be using: intuitive selection (using my intuition as to which features may be most important) as well as some filter methods (variance threshold and correlation measures) and feature importance from decision tree.

All in all I intend on using 4 fear selection methods.

Using the data that was used to train the model and scoring with on the data for which I already have ground truth I intend to retrain each of the models using the methods mentioned above.

So now that is 4 feature selection methods for 4 algorithms, for a total of 16 trained models.

The problem I have now is how to design the experiment to see which models perform better.

What would be a reasonable way to go about this?

My intuition says to take the model fitted by each feature selection method, compute the MAE, and do a pairwise t-test against the deployed model, testing a one-sided hypothesis that the MAE for the new model is less than the MAE in the deployed model.

Should I adjust for multiple comparisons?

Should I instead look to AIC, BIC, or Mallow' C? Are those applicable here? Tree-based models don't fit using maximum likelihood, do they?

Sorry if this is long winded, but writing it out has been helpful. Would love to hear any insights you all have.

Comment: Why would you deviate from standard cross validation and a holdout validation set?

Comment: @Tylerr because I'm not optimizing hyperparameters, I'm trying to select the best model.

Comment: So a model with better cv and holdout performance wouldn't just be the best model? Maybe I am missing something but in a linear model the AIC is an approximation (asymptotically) for cross validation but I wouldn't use the AIC for these models so you should just use the cross validation with the rmse or mae or whatever you think is most important.  And a separate holdout to make doubley sure you aren't overfitting with cv is pretty standard unless you are hurting for training data.

Comment: @Tylerr Thanks, I think I may have been going way deep into my head and reading too much.

Comment: @Tylerr - for reference,  this is what I was reading: https://machinelearningmastery.com/statistical-significance-tests-for-comparing-machine-learning-algorithms/

Comment: Yeah I guess I could see utilizing the pairwise t-test if you need to justify the work of serving a new model to production.  But I mean if nothing is statistically different how would you choose a model? You would probably choose the one with the best accuracy.  If you find a model which IS statistically better, then it is also just better when looking at the cv/validation scores.  So if it isn't a big deal to send a new model into production I would just do the standard stuff.  UNLESS you don't have enough data to do enough validation, then this stuff could be useful-er.